# How to allow only an IP/range access to AWS API Gateway resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, authorization, aws-api-gateway

How best can I restrict access to certain routes in AWS API gateway by IP?
I want to allow only my ECS cluster to access certain routes in API gateway. I tried putting the ECS NAT gateway, the VPC CIDR range in `aws:SourceIp` but always get denied. I even tried my personal computer public IP address ... same results ... Is this the correct way? Or should I try IAM authorizers? The downside with IAM authorizer is I need to sign my API calls? Perhaps using the API Gateway SDK? Which means code change I prefer to avoid.

```
{
  "Id": "MY_API_POLICY",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Condition": {
        "NotIpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": ["XX.XX.XX.XX/32"]
        }
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-*:*:apiid/stagename/*/private/route"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-*:*:apiid/stagename/*/public/route"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Using Amazon API Gateway, you can create private REST APIs that can only be accessed from your Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) using an interface VPC endpoint. Is that helpful?

Comment: @jarmod but I was some apis to be public

Comment: security group for the cluster to block inbound/outbound traffic those ips you don't want it to access,

Comment: Yes resource policy is correct way of restricting ip/range access. Try following https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/control-access-to-your-apis-using-amazon-api-gateway-resource-policies/ to find correct way of doing it.

Comment: @BanjoObayomi if you block only the ports of the security group this might not be sufficient better to block the ip range already at the api gateway

Answer (score 1):

As @Visal already mentioned is restricting the ip/range is the correct way. Here is the example: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/control-access-to-your-apis-using-amazon-api-gateway-resource-policies/

There is an example for a policy that allows the access for a certain ip range:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account_idA>:user/<user>",
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account_idA>:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:<account_idB>:qxz8y9c8a4/*/*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:<account_idB>:qxz8y9c8a4/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": " 203.0.113.0/24"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Or if you want to deny the access then you will find this policy:

```
{
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:<account_idB>:qxz8y9c8a4/*",
    "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
            "aws:SourceIp": "203.0.113.0/24"
        }
    }
}
```