# How to list all Gateway that allow an IP range to everywhere?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

Is there an `aws-cli` in order to list all open ports in an API Gateway similar to the security group as described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html:

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.from-port,Values=22 Name=ip-permission.to-port,Values=22 Name=ip-permission.cidr,Values='0.0.0.0/0' --query "SecurityGroups[*].{Name:GroupName}"
```

The policy in the API Gateway is defined as described here [How to allow only an IP/range access to AWS API Gateway resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857285/how-to-allow-only-an-ip-range-access-to-aws-api-gateway-resources/56768146#56768146):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account_idA>:user/<user>",
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account_idA>:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:<account_idB>:qxz8y9c8a4/*/*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:<account_idB>:qxz8y9c8a4/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

A solution might be to use `list-policies-for-target` with a query but how to find the gateway, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might do it

`aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query "items[?policy != null ].[id,name,policy]" --output text | grep "0.0.0.0"`

You could modify the grep command further to return values that are either accepting or denying.

Comment: The command aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query "items[]" --output text doesn't show the policies of the gateway.

Comment: Which policies are you referring to? It does show the resource policies on the API

Comment: as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html to allow ports. For me no policy is shown with that command but i created these and tested that these are working fine

Comment: For me that command returns a resource policy and the documentation reflects that as well. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-rest-apis.html#output

> items -> (list)
...
policy -> (string)

A stringified JSON policy document that applies to this RestApi regardless of the caller and Method configuration.